# Java Play Framework + H2 Database, Concurrent operation performance

Tags: java, concurrency, playframework, h2

I have a play framework application that uses H2 Database. In general, the application have several scheduled "Jobs" that inserts data into the database (From an external Firebird database), and a controller layer that presents the stored data to the user in xml format via get requests.

My question is, while there is a job inserting data into the database, even just a few lines, the database seems to be unresponsive until the insert operation is complete. (Select queries are waiting until the other operation completes).

i am using standart Play Framework H2 connection string with "MVCC=TRUE" addition.

btw. The server is running on windows platform + Apache Tomcat server.

Is there any additional parameters or settings that i can do to get over this "unresponsiveness" problem ?

Comment: How long does the insert operation take? Usually, inserts are very fast with the H2 database, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, H2 serialized the statements. You have multiple options:

- Insert less data at a time (fewer rows in each statement) so that the database is not blocked for a long time
- [Enable multi-threading using the `multi_threaded` option](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_multi_threaded), but in this case you can not use the `mvcc` feature unfortunately.
- Use a different database.

Comment: i will try to work with multi-threaded option and tell the results.. But so far, im not thinking about switching from h2 database as i am looking for an embedded db and it works great besides this thing..

Comment: Nope, multi_threaded didny help, anyway i've decided to stay like that. those lock ups take just a few seconds and it happens if the data is queried in the same time with the update operations. Thanks anyway